# Unable to get grouped UItableView to scroll to second section when obscured by picker view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll

Stackoverflow seems to be one of the most authoritative and easy to use technical forums on the internet so I figured that this would be the best place to start.  I have done considerable research on this particular issue and so far I have not found a definitive answer and was hoping that someone here would have a solution or at least an answer as to why this is not working.  This is for iPhone SDK 4.1 with xcode 3.2.4.

I have a grouped table view containing 2 sections with 3 rows in each section.  By design the entire table view is visible when not being obscured.  When a user touches any of the cells a picker view is displayed and as selections are made on the picker they are reflected in the selected table view cell.  This picker view obscures the bottom three cells so I would like to have the bottom cells slide up and be visible but when using the following code nothing happens:

```
NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];

[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip
    atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

There are no compiler errors or warnings and I have verified that it is getting executed and that scrolling is enabled on the table view.  As would be expected when unobscured the table view does not scroll but bounces since all of the cells are already visible.  I've thought of a couple of workarounds neither of which are very appealing.  One would be to create two separate table views but this would involve a considerable amount of work since I have proceeded with further development predicated on being able to get the bottom section to scroll.  The other possible solution is to have the frame set to display the picker on the top when selecting from the bottom section and vice versa when selected from the top.  I do not like this solution much for aesthetic reasons.  I am hoping that someone has a solution or at least an explanation for why this is not working as expected.

Many thanks,
Tom

When the table is unobscured by the picker view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, the tableview will not scroll beyond the cells it contains.  Just resize the tableview when the picker view is presented so that they don't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the frame of the tableView and then moving that.

In the UITableViewController :

```
//change the height value to accomodate the pickerView
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,320.0f,240.0f); //guessing on height of 240
self.tableView.frame = newFrame;
```

When you're done, just put it back

```
CGRect oldFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,320.0f,480.0f);
self.tableView.frame = oldFrame;
```

You could always put it in a nice animation block to slide it up or down.

Good luck

Comment: Yes, thanks both of you for the suggestions and the quick responses.  Reducing the size of the frame is the best solution.  And of course doing a little animation will slick it up.  -Tom